# MacBook Pro - Mac OS X 10.5.8

Tags: macos, mac

The operating system of my MacBook Pro is Mac OS X 10.5.8. What is the compatible browser I can safely download?

Comment: where do I look for the answer?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use the built-in version of Safari?

Answer (score 2):

Just use Safari. If not you can try Opera 12

Opera 12 Link: [Opera 12 Download](http://www.opera.com/browser/download/)

Answer (score 1):

Most internet browsers no longer support OS X 10.5.x. I would highly recommend using the built in Safari browser.

However you can find the compatible Google Chrome browser at this address: [Google Chrome OS X 10.5](http://www.oldapps.com/mac/google_chrome.php?old_chrome=9921?download)

If you do decide to download Chrome here are the instructions for the install.

1. Delete the current version of Google Chrome
2. Download the new version
3. Restart your computer